# pendulum involving scipy ode

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I am using scipy ode to solve the pendulum problem.

```
from scipy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import ode

def pendulumdot(t, y,  gamma, omega0, Fd):
    theta, v = y[0], y[1]
    return array([v, -2*gamma*v-omega0**2*sin(theta)+Fd*cos(2*pi*t)])



def pendulum_sample(theta0, thetadot0, gamma, omega0, Fd, t):
    Theta0 = array([theta0, thetadot0]) 
    r = ode(pendulumdot)
    r.set_integrator('dopri5')
    r.set_initial_value(Theta0)
    r.set_f_params( gamma, omega0, Fd)
    #r.set_jac_params()
    theta = zeros(len(t))
    thetadot = zeros(len(t))
    theta[0] = theta0
    thetadot[0] = thetadot0
    for n in range(1, len(t)):
        r.integrate(t[n])
        assert r.successful()
        theta[n] = (r.y)[0]
        thetadot[n] = (r.y)[1]
    return theta, thetadot
def pendulum_demo():
    gamma = 0.1
    omega0 = 10.0
    theta0 = 0.0
    thetadot0 = 0.0
    Fd = 50.0
    t1 = linspace(0, 200, 10000)
    theta1, thetadot1 = pendulum_sample(theta0, thetadot0, gamma, omega0, Fd, t1)
    plt.plot(t1, theta1)
    t2 = linspace(0, 150, 10000)
    theta2, thetadot2 = pendulum_sample(theta0, thetadot0, gamma, omega0, Fd, t2)
    plt.plot(t2, theta2)
    plt.show()
pendulum_demo()
```

I plot two figure of theta versus time for different time range, one is (0, 150) and one is (0, 200). What I expect is that the two figure should be same in the time range (0, 150), however, that is not what I observe. Anything wrong with my script? Thanks.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should use a complete initialization as in

```
r.set_integrator('dopri5', atol=1, rtol = 1e-8)
r.set_initial_value(Theta0, t=t[0])
```

which gives you control over the absolute and relative error thresholds and explicitly sets the initial time.

---

Your system has a Lipschitz constant `L` of about or larger `omega0**2=100`. The error propagation is dominated by the factor `exp(L*(t_final-t))`.

For example, from time 50 to time 150 this factor is `exp(100*100)` which is about `10^4343`. For all practical purposes this means that there is no discernible dependence of the final value on the initial value, i.e., the system is chaotic.

The practical side looks somewhat better than this pessimistic estimate since both curves coincide to about `t=10`. Which means that, assuming the error tolerance is `1e-8`, that `exp(L*10)<=1e+8` or `L=1.84...`. This gives for the interval of size 100 an error magnification factor of `exp(L*100)=1e+80` which is still large enough to call the result chaotic.

Experiments with the error thresholds show that the initial divergence point at about `t=8.4` is insensitive to the relative error. Further, the divergence produces (in my experiments, not your picture) a difference growth from 1 to 24 in `dt=1` which gives about `L=3`, which is still consistent with the last estimate and much less than the theoretical `L=100`.

For a better understanding what happens you should also investigate the derivatives plot,

```
plt.plot(t1,thetadot1,t2,thetadot2)
plt.show()
```

which strikingly demonstrates the origin of the chaotic behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not quite understanding your answer. Is this chaotic behavior caused by programming or by the physics law which can not be avoided.

Comment: By the physics and the chosen constants, which are presumably also part of the physics. Did you look at the derivatives? Even the choice of the stepsize control strategy could lead to different numerical solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the patience. I have watched the derivatives and it turns out after a period of  time, the two derivative tend to be identical. Why the derivatives tend to be identical at last?

Comment: Does not look like that in my version. As far as the wild oscillations allow to see it, the two derivative graphs may overlap for a little longer than the functions, but in the end they are quite different, having different amplitude etc.

Comment: I have uploaded a figure of derivative. Are you using my script to run the simulation?

Comment: Yes, the same script with the indicated modifications and trying out different step size control parameters, like `atol=1e-12, rtol = 1e-16` etc. The qualitative picture remains the same, the concrete graphs are all different. Are you sure that the velocities are for the same run as the position graph? The velocities suggest a very early switch to simple oscillations in the blue curve.